# Why isn't "white" related to colour and ''God save the King" with a god?

Tags: meaning, e-m-forster, a-passage-to-india

I first stumbled on this quote at [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/a-passage-to-india-quotes-741015):

> he did not realize that 'white' has no more to do with a colour than '*God save the King*' with a god, and that it is the height of impropriety to consider what **it** does connote.
>
> — E. M. Forster (1924), [*A Passage to India*, chapter 7](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.463445/page/n77).

1. How doesn't "white" relate to skin colour? Most European Caucasians do have lighter skin.
2. How doesn't  'God save the King' relate to a god? Doesn't it refer to the [Church of England's God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Save_the_Queen#Lyrics_in_the_UK)?
3. What does "**it**" connote?
4. Why is "the height of impropriety to consider what it does connote"?

Answer (score 5):

If you read the rest of the paragraph, it's clear that Mr Fielding thinks "white" is an inaccurate description of a Caucasian's skin (it should be "pinko-grey"). The narrator is saying that being "white" is not about skin colour; the implication is that "white" represents *racial superiority* rather than skin tone.

The narrator sees a corollary with *God Save the King*, which ostensibly is a prayer for divine protection of the monarch, but in practice can be seen as a purely self-serving utterance, whether as a pledge of loyalty to the monarchy, or as a fervent wish that everything that the monarchy represents (imperial power, social stability, British hegemony) should continue. It doesn't require a belief in a god, just as being "white" doesn't require a particular skin colour.

Of course it would be improper to say these things: one shouldn't draw attention to one's (assumed) superiority, firstly because a cultured person should have better manners than that, and secondly because expressing a belief in the right to rule over the "lesser" races may not exactly be welcomed out there in the colonies.